# How to reference resources in other subscriptions with Bicep?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I use Bicep to create an Azure Function using an app service plan that was created earlier in another subscription.

I get the following error:

```
{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"NotFound","message":"{\r\n  \"Code\": \"NotFound\",\r\n  \"Message\": \"Cannot find ServerFarm with name asp-intsharedep-prod.\",\r\n  \"Target\": null,\r\n  \"Details\": [\r\n    {\r\n      \"Message\": \"Cannot find ServerFarm with name myasp.\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"Code\": \"NotFound\"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      \"ErrorEntity\": {\r\n        \"ExtendedCode\": \"51004\",\r\n        \"MessageTemplate\": \"Cannot find {0} with name {1}.\",\r\n        \"Parameters\": [\r\n          \"ServerFarm\",\r\n          \"myasp\"\r\n        ],\r\n        \"Code\": \"NotFound\",\r\n        \"Message\": \"Cannot find ServerFarm with name myasp.\"\r\n      }\r\n    }\r\n  ],\r\n  \"Innererror\": null\r\n}"}]}}
```

It is only a simple bicep file, no modules, no targetScope. I refer to my app service plan by:

```
resource serverFarm 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2020-06-01'  existing = {
  name: aspName
  scope: resourceGroup('subscriptionid','rg-shared-asp')
}
```

Is it not possible to reference app service plans in other subscriptions?

Comment: Do you have read ermissions on the other subscription with the user account / service principal you're using to deploy your bicep file ?

Comment: Have you tried to directly reference the `serverFarmId` using something like that: `resourceId('subscriptionid', 'rg-shared-asp', 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', aspName)`

Comment: I have read permisson and I have the samme error when i use  a reference with the resourceId method.

Answer (score 3):

The default target scope is resourcegroup. So if you don't state a target scope, the resourcegroup scope is set implicitly. The available scopes are **resource group, subscription, management group, and tenant**. So if the other subscription is under the same tenant or management group, you can set the scope to either of them. For example, state in your bicep file:

```
targetScope = 'tenant'
```

And on az cli:

```
az deployment tenant create \
  --name demoTenantDeployment \
  --location WestUS \
  --template-file main.bicep
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/scope-extension-resources#apply-at-deployment-scope

Comment: But does I really need to do a deploy at management group level? I want to do a deploy a resource group and I need to reference a app service plan in a other subscription.

Comment: @alefa240 Are your subscriptions under the same tenant or management group?

Comment: Yes is it in the same tenant.

Comment: @alefa240, I have updated the content for the tenant target scope. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I guess it will works when doing a deploy at tenant scope. The need to reach the asp in a different subscription disappeared, so i havent have  the possibilities to test the solution.